# Ios horizontal scrollview and autolayout issue

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, horizontal-scrolling

Folks,
in my swift app i have a horizontal scrollview (**black border**) and i am adding images programatically. Scrollview is given zero contraints for nearest views. height should be adjusted in runtime but in my case i am getting weird result.

for iphone 4s the scrollview fits correctly. but for iphone 6 scrollview height is set to `493`

[image]

Iphone 4s

[image]

But in iphone6 screens height is always lower than the actual height

[image]

Comment: Please provide `adding images programmatically` code.

Comment: When you say "Scrollview is given zero constraints" do you mean constraints are set to 0, or that you have no constraints set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set content mode of UIImage programatically

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Comment: Yes. Problem is with contentmode of the image. thanks alot.